# How do i view recent records from SQL table?

Tags: sql

I have one table called "Mydata"
with date,name,address columns
this table is having more than 5000 records now i dont want to view all 5000 records 
I just want to view recently added 100 records,
how can i do that I tried with 
select top 100 * from Mydata
But which is not giving me recently added records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `TOP 100 *` to work as you desire, you need to specify the order in which to return the records. Use the example below and replace `[YourField]` with whatever column determines the order in which the records were inserted.

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM       Mydata
ORDER BY   [YourField] DESC --Could be the date added column, or the primary key.
```

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of the data is not guaranteed. Well that's not entirely correct as you can cluster there data by a field. However unless put the insertion data an time on the row in a field, you can't query by that.

So add a column (say called insdate) to your table what puts the current date and time into the row when you insert it. Then query by date time ordering

```
select top 100 * from mydata order by insdate desc
```

Like james hill says, you can use any column to indicate the ordering if the value is unique and changes in the same way.